# iOS toolbar sometimes highlights/selects the wrong button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar, highlight

I have an iOS app that, in one view, makes a toolbar in code.  Nothing fancy here; just a bunch of standard UIBarButtonItems (initialized with initWithImage, and each one invoking a different selector), added (along with spacers) to the toolbar using UIToolbar setItems:animated (with no animation).

This works fine most of the time... but sometimes, after going to another view and back to this one many times, the toolbar's touch-handling appears to be off.  It highlights and invokes the wrong button.  It's not always the same wrong button, either; sometimes it's one right next to the one I actually tapped, but other times it is further away, even clear over on the other side of the toolbar.

There is no pattern to it, but if you try long enough (switching to another view and then back to this one), it always happens.  It seems to happen more often when the other view is at a different screen orientation (forced by its shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation implementation), but even when all views have the same orientation, it still happens now and then.  When it happens, my selector gets invoked with a sender that matches the button that was actually highlighted, rather than the one I touched.  So it really seems to be a matter of something in iOS not processing the touch correctly.

My google-fu has utterly failed to turn up any other reports of this issue... seems like it must be an Apple bug, since none of my code is involved in the toolbar touch handling.  This happens both in the simulator and on the device, under iOS 4.3 (haven't tried other versions yet).

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Any suggestions on how to avoid it?

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the code where you create the Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem.  It wasn't the code that creates the toolbar itself; it was where (and how often!) it was being called.

This was legacy code, and we hadn't noticed that the create-the-toolbar code was being called from the view's didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method (for reasons we can't imagine).  That method gets invoked quite frequently, and the old toolbar wasn't being torn down, so it was creating toolbars on top of toolbars.  Not too surprising that the touch handling went wonky in that situation.

Deleting the call there (and putting it in viewDidLoad like one would expect) solved the problem.  Sorry for wasting everybody's time... but maybe the next person to stumble across screwy toolbar behavior will find this helpful.